# Windows 8 Phone wait for BeginGetRequestStream to finish

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest

I have the following code which im using to connect a REST

```
    public void aquireToken() 
    {
         HttpWebRequest apiR = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(apiUrl + "authorize?"));
        apiR.Method = "POST";

        apiR.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        apiR.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), apiR);
    }



    private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
        // End the stream request operation
        Stream postStream = myRequest.EndGetRequestStream(callbackResult);

        // Create the post data
        string postData = "username=" + NTUser.username + "&appId=" + appId + "&signed=" + CreateSignedHex();


        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        // Add the post data to the web request
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        postStream.Close();

        // Start the web request
        myRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponsetStreamCallback), myRequest);
    }

    private void GetResponsetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);
        using (StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            var u = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);

            //string jsondata = u.data.toString();


            NTUser.token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(u.data.ToString());


        }
    }
```

The problem is when calling the aquireToken method from the Phone UI, it doesn't wait on the httprequest to finish, which cause in nullreferences, because the next UI page is trying to access data which isn't loaded yet..

How do i present a simple loader on the UI thread while getting the needed information from the API?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the code to complete. One way of doing that is passing another argument to acquireToken which will e called when the operation is done.

In that way, the UI calling the acquireRoken method knows to use the data only when the callbabl is called.

One way of showing a "loading UI" on your page is to place a 'Grid’ element with background of black or white that is semi transparent and has its visibility set to Collapsed. Place a progress bar in that grid. While loading, change the visibility of said grid to Visible, thus blocking the UI and letting your sea you are doing something.

```
public void DoUIThings()
{
     // Do some UI related things.
     acquireToken();
     // Don't continue doing things here.... Wait for the ContinueDoUIThings() to be called.
}

public void ContinueDoUIThings()
{
      // Now use your newly created token here...
      // Do some UI related things.
      // Note that this is called from below.
}

public void aquireToken() 
{
    // .... Your code was here..
    apiR.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), apiR);
}

private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
{
    /// Your code was here.....
    myRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponsetStreamCallback), myRequest);
}

private void GetResponsetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);
    using (StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        var u = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);

        //string jsondata = u.data.toString();
        NTUser.token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(u.data.ToString());

        // Added this call here...
        ContinueDoUIThings();

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to follow any of your answers.. Can you give an example of usages?

Comment: You need to use the callback (GetResponsetStreamCallback) to issue the continuation of the UI call. Adding pseudo-example in the answer.